# Angular setting default radio selection in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am presenting a simple yes/no answer question to my users and I want to have a default radio button selected. The problem is that I could have any number of these questions presented to the user.

This is my code:

```
<div ng-form ng-repeat="i in offers track by $index" name="messageForm[$index]">  
     <div data-ng-repeat="option in closeListingOptions" class="radio">
          <label>
               <input type="radio" name="close" ng-model="i.close" value="{{option.id}}" ng-checked="option.checked" />{{option.name}}</strong>
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

My options are set as follows:

```
$scope.closeListingOptions = [
        {
            id: "1",
            name: "Yes please",
            checked: true
        },
        {
            id: "0",
            name: "No thanks",
            checked: false
        }     
];
```

The above example works and check/sets "yes" as the default answer. However unless I manually select an option via a mouse click the value is not binding to the model.

I have read that ng-select should not be used with ng-options but i am not sure how else I can achieve this goal? It seems that I need something like:

```
i.close = "1":
```

But how can I set this for an unknown quntity since I don't know how many question will be presented?

Answer (score 1):

**1-** Instead of `value={{something}}` you can use `ng-value` directive.

**2-** Each input pack should have its specific `name`.

Here is a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.offers = [{
      number: 1
    },
    {
      number: 2
    }
  ];


  $scope.closeListingOptions = [{
      id: "1",
      name: "Yes please",
      checked: true
    },
    {
      id: "0",
      name: "No thanks",
      checked: false
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-form ng-repeat="i in offers" name="messageForm[$index]">
    <div data-ng-repeat="option in closeListingOptions" class="radio">
      <label>
               <input type="radio" name="close-{{i.number}}" ng-model="i.close" ng-value="option.id" ng-checked="option.checked" />{{option.name}}</strong>
          </label>
    </div>
    {{i}}
    <hr>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you but your solution doen't quite fit my use case since I don't access to the $scope.offers in order to manipulate it by adding the "close: 1" value

Comment: What you mean `I don't access to the $scope.offers`?  It is on client side and you can manipulate it. Also, your `ng-model="i.close"` says that each offers item has `close` key. has not? @AlanA

Comment: It is client side but is called via an API which makes a call to a backend db. It would be a hack for me to inject data into the result of a mysql query. That is correct - the close key does not exist for each offer - my error

Comment: So, is your `ng-model="i.close"` wrong? If your offers items don't have the `close` key, This binding will add that to item. I can't understand your problem! @AlanA

Comment: The only reason I have i.close is so that in my controller I know what the 'close' response was to any given question. So if it adds the binding I guess htat is what I want

Comment: Yes, Run my snippet again. It will add that key to items. @AlanA

Comment: Your snippet doesn't select an answer by default and bind as per my original question though

Comment: That's because the models are not defined! You can add the `close` key to items after receiving data from API. `ng-checked` directive does not help you according to [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) @AlanA

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
<input type="radio" name="close" 
    ng-model="option.checked" value="{{option.id}}"
    ng-checked="option.checked" />{{option.name}}</strong>
```

This `ng-model` will updated the `checked` key of your data array and then you can fetch all the radio button selection as per their ids from that single variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able t achieve my goal with the following:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="option in closeListingOptions" class="radio" ng-init="i.closeListing = 1">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="close-{{i.id}}" ng-model="i.closeListing" ng-value="{{option.id}}" />
        <strong>{{option.name}}</strong>
    </label>
</div>
```

The solution was to use ng-init